# Using $ Instead of querySelector in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

In the Chrome console:

```
$$('[data-test="template-input--row"]').find(node => node.querySelector('[data-test="template-input--name"]').innerText === 'ATTACH')
```

returns correctly without any error.

Replacing querySelector with `$` throws an error, even though this works as expected in [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io).

```
$$('[data-test="template-input--row"]').find(node => node.$('[data-test="template-input--name"]').innerText === 'ATTACH')
```

> Uncaught TypeError: node.$ is not a function
>       at :1:59
>       at Array.find ()
>       at :1:41

How can I make the script (Chrome console) using the `$` to return the node without throwing the TypeError?

```
<div class="table__row" data-test="template-input--row"><div class="table__td--double-width table__td" data-test="template-input--name">ATTACH</div>
```

Comment: `$` is a global (or actually, a local variable in the console's eval scope) variable. It is not a method of any object like `node`.

Comment: Have you tried `browser.$`? The [docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$.html) suggest that `$` is either a global variable or on the `browser` object (not the `node` object).

Answer (score 1):

The `$` thing is not a method, it's a function. So you cannot call `node.$()`. However, as per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#queryselector), `$` function accepts second argument `startNode`, so you can try this:

```
$$('[data-test="template-input--row"]').find(node => 
  $('[data-test="template-input--name"]', node).innerText === 'ATTACH'
)
```

Comment: @RSSregex you need to tell us where this `$` thing comes from. Did you include jquery or any other thing that expose a `$` global in your runtime? Or do you mean `$` ref to chrome console built-in utility? I assumed the later, but clearly my assumption was wrong.